# MySQL optimizations - poor innodb settings or insufficient hardware?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I'm currently trying to optimize my MySQL database (running innodb engine) for my requests that are mainly INSERT and UPDATE statements.

I'm using a very basic server with 2GB memory/2 CPU's and a 40GB disk. I've gone through much of the MySQL docs, including optimization (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb-diskio.html) and memory use (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-use.html).

I've set my my.conf file to as follows:

```
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine = innodb
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2147483648
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 4 
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size = 1073741824 
innodb_change_buffer_max_size=30
```

Despite increasing the pool size, chunk size and number of instances, I'm still seeing significant query bottlenecks and the both CPU's are running at 100%.

Is there annoying more I can do on the innodb engine to reduce these bottlenecks? Or is it simply a case of using greater spec hardware?

Comment: 2Gbytes of memory is not very much (doesn't my phone have about that much RAM?).  However, if you want to optimize a query load, it is important to understand the query load.  This may or may not be a hardware/software problem.

Comment: One thing you can check is adding indexes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks - I'm just trying to see how much I can eek out of a small server, could you expand on 'query load'?

Comment: Is that a virtual machine? I don't know where to buy a 2GB hardware. But no hardware or settings will help you much, if you run poorly optimized queries.

Comment: Voting to move this question to dba.stackexchange.com. It's a fine question, but probably a better fit for that site since this question does not mention any programming problem.

Answer (score 3):

`innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2147483648` will *NOT* work on a 2GB server.  Change to `300M`.

You have a tiny machine; if you increased any other settings, revert the changes!

Let's see your `my.cnf`; there may be some settings to shrink so that you can fit in 2GB (or 2GiB) of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

The poor innodb settings is for sure. 
Your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is larger than 2GB, it is 2GiB.. It should not even close as everyone suggested and also documented.

may be also insufficient hardware, and even bad programmed SQL.